# LibreOffice LaTeX Extension?

Tags: libre-office

Currently, it appears as though there are two extensions that support LaTeX in LibreOffice. It seems historically everyone has used TeXMaths, but there's also Writer2LaTeX but I see nothing about it. Is there a reason to avoid Writer2LaTeX or is there a reason for taking a preference to one over the other?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I checked out Writer2Latex. It didn't seem to work on my newer version of LO.

Comment: And there ist calc2latex as well, which I'm using once in a while.

Comment: Use this: https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/texmaths-1 Also check out: https://askubuntu.com/a/1068048/777279